# Delimited data and using a delimiter

Tags: python

Write a program which accepts a row of delimited data and the delimiter used from the user. In your program implement a Class with Public Properties to set the Data Row and the Delimiter value with a Function which parses the data row and returns the individual data fields to the screen.

```
data_row = str(input("Enter your data row: "))
delimiter = str(input("Enter your delimter: "))

a = data_row.split(delimiter)

while a:
    print(a[])
```

When I input the information, such as `Carl#Mate#America#World`
and the delimiter is going to be the `#`

I can't get it to print each piece of data individually, it should appear as this:

```
Carl
Mate
America
World
```

Comment: You're using Python 3, right? `str(input())` is redundant since `input()` already returns a string.

Comment: Note this has nothing to do with the delimiter. Your loop is wrong: `a[]` is invalid, and `while a` will always be true since you don't modify `a` in the loop. You might have meant `a.pop(0)` instead of `a[]`. In future, please make a [mcve]. It will help you understand the problem (in this case the loop, not the delimiter) and allow people to help you more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
data_row = str(input("Enter your data row: "))
delimiter = str(input("Enter your delimiter: "))

list_of_elems = data_row.split(delimiter)

for elem in list_of_elems:
    print(elem)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 delimiter.py 
Enter your data row: a,b,c,d  
Enter your delimiter: ,
a
b
c
d
>>> python3 delimiter.py 
Enter your data row: z#x#c#v
Enter your delimiter: #
z
x
c
v
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for word in a:
    print(word)
```